# How to debug a QT MCU project into QTcreator and IMXRT1052 evaluation board?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, nxp-microcontroller, segger-jlink, mcu

I have a QT commercial license so i'm able to devolop a qt for mcu project.I have also a NXP IMXRT1052 evaluaton board.I developed a simple app with a single qml file and a c++ class.Now i want to set the debugger into qt creator.This is my qt for mcu kit configuration

1. kit config
   [image]
2. debbuger config
   [image]
3. mcu device config
   [image]
4. bare metal device config
   [image]

So i want to know how to debug into qt creator of my qt for mcu app.  i successful flashed the IMXRT  evaluation  board and run in release mode my app. If i select run into debug nothing work and i'm not able to flash and debug my app. Is there an error into my configuration ??

Comment: "i successful flashed the IMXRT evaluation board and run in release mode my app. If i select run into debug nothing work and i'm not able to flash and debug my app."
So the applications downloads and runs successfully in with a release build, but with a debug build, the download/"flash" fails? Or does the download succeed and debugging fails?

Comment: yes the download/flash fails!!! I push debug button of qt creator to download!!

Answer (score 1):

Since the download succeeds using the release build but fails using the debug build, the hardware setup seems to be working in general.

You are using a J-Link debug probe, correct?
Since the release build is working, I suggest to compare a working J-Link log file (release) against a non-working J-Link log file (debug).

From the screenshot it looks like you are using windows.

1. Open J-Link Commander (or any other programs which connect to J-Link)
2. Click the small green J-Link icon in the windows task bar
3. Switch to the *Settings* tab in the J-Link Web Control Panel
4. Check the *Override* checkbox in the Log file section.
5. Close J-Link Commander

More infos on J-Link log files can be found here:
https://wiki.segger.com/Enable_J-Link_log_file